# Silverlight databinding internal workings

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, internals

Does anyone know how the databinding system works in silverlight technically, I have seen alot of the tuts on databinding and that items must be bound to a Dependancy Object ( and dependants ) using dependancy properties but where are the properties actually managed? what classes should I look at in reflector to understand the internals? I want a deeper look can anyone explain it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data binding is handled by the unmanaged stack so you can't exactly do it but you can look at the stack in wpf a little easier. Essentially, the DependencyObject stuff is so that execution of changes is a lot faster than reflection can do.  Remember this stack is also responsible for animation changes.  (30-60x second).